# Problems with glossaries package and complex symbols

Tags: glossaries

The glossaries package doesn't work with complex symbols as the example shows below. Is there a workaround available?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{symb}
{
    name={\ensuremath{\overset{\rightarrow}{A}}},
    description={Description},
}

\begin{document}
  works: $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$\\
  doesn't work: \gls{symb}

  \printglossary[type=main]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see an error message *only* for the command `\overset`, so the most logical thing to do is switch to `\vec{A}`, that works correctly. On an alternative, add `\protect` before the command `overset`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

### Convert `\overset` to `\vec`

Substituting the first command to the standard vector notation gives a different, non-customizable arrow format; so the given arrow notation can be used in your document to indicate vectors (at your discrection even user-defined parameter conventions).

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{glossaries}
%
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{symb}{%
 name={\ensuremath{\vec{A}}},
 description={Description}%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
Works: $\vec{A}$ \\
Now even this one works: \gls{symb}
\printglossary[type=main]
%
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

### Protect the command `\overset`

If you want more customization inside the overset arguments, simply protect this command inside the definition of `\ensuremath{}` by adding `\protect` before the considered lines of code *only* inside the name field.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{glossaries}
%
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{symb}{%
 name={\ensuremath{\protect\overset{\rightarrow}{A}}}, % this is now protected
 description={Description}%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
Works: $\overset{\rightarrow}{A}$\\
Now even this one works: \gls{symb}
\printglossary[type=main]
%
\end{document}
```

And here is the desired output:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! As I have other "complex" symbols, the \protect command does the trick.

Comment: @user4811 You're welcome, it's always a pleasure to help `;-)`.